# Server Sent Events : Not working

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, notifications, server-sent-events

I am using [HTML5 Server-Sent Events](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp).

Actually I need to show notification (new record enter and which are unread) that's when any new record is insert in database (php/mysql).

So for testing purpose I just tried with count of total row. But I am getting this error message in my local-host:

> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at http://**localhost**/project/folder/servevent/demo_sse.php.

The line is:

```
var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
```

I have tried this:

**index.php**

```
<script>
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
    var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.data;
    };
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
}
</script> 
<div id="result"></div>
```

**demo_sse.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); // your host, user, password
  if(!$db) { echo mysql_error(); }
$select_db = mysql_select_db("testdatase"); // database name
  if(!$select_db) { echo mysql_error(); }

$time = " SELECT count( id ) AS ct FROM `product` ";
$result = mysql_query($time);
$resa = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $resa['ct'];
flush();
?>
```

Please let me know what going wrong.

I know for notification we can use Ajax with some interval time, but I don't want such thing. As I have N number of records and which may slow my resources.

Comment: i check my query is working fine.. its resulting me count of 5 , as in my table there is 5 record .. but dont know why its not showing with server side events

Comment: Did you know what was the problem?

Comment: no...actually i forget to test on this module ...

Answer (score 7):

According to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp),

There are several 'rules' that need to be met, and yours is lacking at this point:

- Output the data to send (Always start with "data: ")

It is somehow like:

```
echo "data: {$resa['ct']}\n\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting a header to `text/event-stream` worked for me:

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

// Rest of PHP code
```

Answer (score 0):

Please modify the following code snippet according to your requirements

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

// infinite loop
while (1) {
    // output the current timestamp; REPLACE WITH YOUR FUNCTIONALITY
    $time = date('r');
    echo "data: Server time: {$time}\n\n"; // 2 new line characters

    ob_end_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(2); // wait for 2 seconds
}

?>
```

I tested this code snippet myself; it's working for me. If you have any query, let me know.